# PHP SQL Result stored as var in new sql query

Tags: php, mysql

So its a php game etc...

This is the main part of my script;

```
$sql = "SELECT * from search1 WHERE username='Hitachi'";
$result = mysqli_query($connection, $sql);

while ($rows = mysqli_fetch_array($result)) {
    $timeleft = $rows['time'];
    $target55 = $rows['target'];
    $id = $rows['id'];
    $status = $rows['status'];
    $hours = $rows['hours'];
    $started = $rows['started'];
    $deletetime = $started - 86400;

    mysqli_query($connection, "DELETE FROM search WHERE started<'$deletetime'");
    $starttime = $started;
    $time1 = $starttime + 10800;

    $a_query = mysqli_query($connection, "SELECT * FROM BG WHERE username='$target55' AND status='Ready'");
    $check_found = mysqli_num_rows($a_query);

    if ($check_found >= 1) {
        $bg = mysqli_query($connection, "SELECT * FROM BG WHERE status='Ready' AND username='$target55' ORDER by slot DESC LIMIT 1");
        while ($i = mysqli_fetch_object($bg)) {
            $bg1 = $i->bodyguard;
        }

        echo "This user has a bodyguard called <b>$bg1</b>!";
        if ($time1 < time() && $hours >= 3 || $userlevel >= 14) {
            $sql2 = "SELECT * from users WHERE username='$target55'";
            $result2 = mysqli_query($connection, $sql2);
            while ($rows2 = mysqli_fetch_array($result2)) {
                $target_country = $rows2['country'];
            }

            mysqli_query($connection, "UPDATE search1 SET status='2', location='$target_country', found='$target_country' WHERE id='$id'");
        }

        mysqli_query($connection, "DELETE FROM BG WHERE username='$target55'");
```

This does nothing at all regardless if there is a bodyguard or not.
If i remove the check for the bodyguard etc then it works however i need it to check?

Comment: Enable PHP error reporting, add `<?php error_reporting(E_ALL); ini_set("display_errors", 1);` at the top of your file. Then implement proper error-handling for your queries, right now you're just assuming they're all good and always succeed. Learn about [`mysqli::error`](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.error.php). That should tell you what's broken. Then, learn about paramaterized queries with placeholders, [`mysqli::prepare()`](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.prepare.php) - that's really important security-wise. You should also clean your code a bit, this is a bit messy to read ;-)

Comment: I am not getting any errors when adding the error_reporting, it all works if i remove the bodyguard check but when i add that in, when it should pass (No bodyguard) it does nothing and when there is a bodyguard it doesn't say there is?

Comment: I took the liberty of formatting your code a bit. Wasn't that ***much*** easier to read? ;-) Like I said, you should get the error thrown back from MySQL too (if any) with `echo mysqli_error($connection);`. And are you sure that the `$bg` query returned any rows? It can also be a logical error (as if your `if`s aren't checking for the right things, or accounting for all possibilities).

Comment: $target55 at the moment will not return any rows therefore it should carry on the "update search1 set..." sql query.

When there is rows it should display $b1 query?

Also it is much easier to read, Thanks

Comment: If you look at the indenting, you see that the query where you update is inside that if, so if there are no rows, it will never reach that far and execute the update